# Forming triplets from pairs

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I'm given $\binom{n}{2}$ pairs of numbers. What is the maximum number of triples (there are $\binom{n}{3}$ of them) I can form by using 3 pairs for every triplet? For example, I can use $(2,5),(5,8),(8,2)$ to form the triplet $(2,5,8)$. Remember that I can only use each pair once.

I've tried systematically counting, first counting each triplet with 1 in it, then 2, etc. but I found it to be very messy.

What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To use them all you are asking for a [Steiner triple system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system) $(2,3,n)$  These exist whenever $n\equiv 1,3 \pmod 6$

Comment: It could be for small numbers because they interfere.

Comment: What would be the maximum if $n$ was not $1,3\mod6$?